# iOS - Single delegate to multiple objects. How to vary behavior?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a UIViewController which is also a NSURLConnectionDelegate. As such, it defines behavior such as:

```
– connection:didReceiveResponse: 
– connection:didReceiveData: 
– connectionDidFinishLoading:
```

However, in this view I have multiple NSURLConnections which assign it as the delegate. I need to achieve custom behavior in connectionDidFinishLoading: depending on which object is calling the delegate (e.g playing audio vs displaying an image vs opening a link)

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Each of the delegate methods pass in the NSURLConnection as a parameter. Store a reference to your connection in a property and then check the if the connection parameter passed into connectionDidFinishLoading is your audio connection or your image connection etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare each of the connection

```
@interface YourViewController
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSURLConnection *audioConnection;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSURLConnection *anotherConnection;
```

then, on your connectionDidFinishLoading: method call each connection like this:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
     if (connection == audioConnection) {
           //doSomething
     } else if (connection == anotherConnection) {
           //doSomethingElse
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of urlconnections which falls under different categories(say 10 connections out of 5 are for audio, 3 for display image, 2 for opening link etc..), better option is to  subclass `NSURLConnection` and create a custom `NSURLConnection` class. You can add your own property like a tag to this class. And define your own custom tags to different type of connections. In your `UIViewController` and delegate methods try to use this subclass object and use this `tag` property to differentiate between different `NSURLConnections`.

For eg:-

Create a `CustomNSURLConnection` file and write,

```
#define kAudioConnectionTag 100
#define kDisplayConnectionTag 200
#define kOpenURLConnectionTag 300

@interface CustomNSURLConnection : NSURLConnection 

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger tag;
```

In `UIViewController` class,

```
CustomNSURLConnection *audioConnection = [CustomNSURLConnection ...];
audioConnection.tag = kAudioConnectionTag;

CustomNSURLConnection *displayConnection = [CustomNSURLConnection ...];
audioConnection.tag = kDisplayConnectionTag;

CustomNSURLConnection *openURLConnection = [CustomNSURLConnection ...];
audioConnection.tag = kOpenURLConnectionTag;

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(CustomNSURLConnection *)connection{
     if (connection.tag == kAudioConnectionTag) {
           //code
     } else if (connection.tag == kDisplayConnectionTag) {
           //code
     } else {
           //code
     }
}
```